# How to find the item in a list whose f(item) is the smallest?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I have a list, `l` and a function `f`. `f` is not strictly increasing or decreasing. How can I find the item in the list whose `f(item)` is the smallest? For example, let's say the list is:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and `list(f(x)for x in l)` is:

```
[2, 9, 0, 3]
```

`f(3)` is smaller than f of any of the other ones, so it should print "3". What's the shortest way to do this? I initially tried:

```
min(f(x) for x in l)
```

But this gives `0`, not `3`. If I was shooting for readability, not brevity, I would do:

```
index = 0
smallest = f(l[0])
for i in range(len(l)):
    value = f(l[i])
    if value < smallest:
        smallest = value
        index = i
```

This is fine, but horrendous for code-golf. Even if it was golfed

```
i,s=0,f(l[0])
for x in range(len(l)):
 v=f(l[x])
 if v<s:s,i=v,x
```

This is a bad solution. The shortest solution I can think of is:

```
g=[f(x)for x in l];print(l[g.index(min(g))])
```

(44 bytes) How can I golf this down further?

Comment: Just `min(l,key=f)`.

Comment: @vaultah Post that as an answer.

Comment: @vaultah Wow. That is embarrassingly simple. I feel like an idiot now. Thanks! If you post that, I'd accept it.

Comment: This kind of question isn't for code golf, but for stackoverflow or some other subsection of stackexchange. Voting to close as off-topic

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny This is a [tag:tips] question. That is on-topic.

Comment: @trichoplax actually I think it's this one: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/31625

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman you're right - I just reread the title... Thanks :)

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ the fact that an elegant solution comes along doesn't change that it's a good question...

Comment: Does the answer have to be in Python?

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ In general for code-golf, no. However, this isn't a code-golf question, but a [tag:tips] question (about code-golf).

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ Still doesn't hurt, does it? ;-)

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Perhaps make it general, not limited to Python? It may be interesting to see how to do that in different languages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use `key` property of `min`

As @vaultah said, use `min(l,key=f)`. `min(l,key=f)` takes the minimum of `f(i)` for `i` in `l`.

It is also possible to apply this to `max`, and `sorted`. For example, `max(l,key=f)` is the maximum of `f(i)` for `i` in `l`. For `sorted`, the usage would be: `sorted(l,key=f)`.

Comment: I'm accepting this for now, but will accept an answer from @vaultah if he posts it.